# How can return UIView views along with its subviews in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to create a stack of rounded circle views like this.

[UIView stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OBkM.png)
I want to return this whole stack of `UIViews` at once. So I tried in this way.

```
open func setupCirclestack(parentFrame:CGRect)->UIView
{
    let arrayColor=[UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.red]
    let baseCircle=Circle.init(frame: parentFrame)
    baseCircle.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple
    var parentview=baseCircle
   // var existingFrame=baseCircle.frame

    for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
    {
      let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame)
        circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
        parentview.addSubview(circle)
        parentview=circle as! Circle

      //existingFrame=circle.frame

    }

    return parentview
}

func getInnerCircle(currentFrame:CGRect)->UIView
{
    CircleValues.sharedInstance.radius=CircleValues.sharedInstance.radius-30
    print("New Radius------\(CircleValues.sharedInstance.radius)")
    let circle=Circle.init(frame: currentFrame)
    return circle




}
```

But I can get only the last (inner most view) view. How can I return the whole stack of `UIViews` from this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your all the frames for all the circles are same as `parentFrame`.

So, your all views are adding but you can only able to see last  view as it is overlaps other views!

You have to decrease your frame size for every iteration of your for loop for every child view you are adding!

```
 for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
{
  let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame) // decrease size(height and width) here every time to achieve result attached in screenshot in your question
    circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
    parentview.addSubview(circle)
    parentview=circle as! Circle

  //existingFrame=circle.frame

}
```

Comment: After adding all the views and if I returend the parentview will it return my whole stack?

Answer (score 1):

You reasign a parentView variable at the end of for loop, So it will replace existing object of parentView in which you added the circle as a subview. Therefore it will return a last circle object which is stored in parentView.

```
for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
{
  let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame)
    circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
    parentview.addSubview(circle)
    //parentview=circle as! Circle

  //existingFrame=circle.frame

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return views inside your parent view you need to change your function to something like this:

```
    open func setupCirclestack(parentFrame:CGRect)->UIView
    {
        let arrayColor=[UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.red]
        let baseCircle=Circle.init(frame: parentFrame)
        baseCircle.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple
        var parentview=baseCircle
       // var existingFrame=baseCircle.frame

        for i in 0...2//<CircleValues().numberOfCircles-1
        {
          let circle=self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame)
            circle.backgroundColor=arrayColor[i]
            parentview.addSubview(circle)

        }

        return parentview
    }
```

But if you need to return array of views, try this:

```
    open func setupCirclestack(parentFrame:CGRect)->[UIView]
    {
        let arrayColor = [UIColor.yellow,UIColor.blue,UIColor.red]
        let baseCircle = Circle.init(frame: parentFrame)
        baseCircle.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple

        var circleArray = [Circle]()

        for i in 0...2
        {
            let circle = self.getInnerCircle(currentFrame: parentFrame)
            circle.backgroundColor = arrayColor[i]

            circleArray.append(circle)

        }

        return circleArray
    }
```